# how to share my keys that i saved on a node in redis cluster to all nodes?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

So basically the problem is that I'm saving my keys on a specific node in a redis cluster, but I would like it to be saved on all nodes and have this redundancy, how could I do that?

I got a result similar to what I want using SETSLOT, importing keys from one node to another, but I wanted a more efficient way to do this

Comment: If you need it just for redundancy purpose, you can add replicas to your master node instead of keeping copy of each key on all master nodes.